# How do I enforce uniqueness against four columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, tags, indexing

In SQL Server 2012, I have a 'cross-reference' table containing four columns.  The combination of the four columns must be unique.  My initial thought was to simply create a a primary key containing all four columns, but some research has suggested that this might not be a good idea.

**Background to question...**
I am trying to implement a tagging service on a legacy web application.  Some of the objects that need tagging use a uniqueidentifier as their primary key, whilst others use a simple integer id.  I have approached this using a 'two-table' approach.  One table contains the tags, whilst the other table provides a reference between the objects to be tagged and the tag table.  This table I have name TagList...

```
CREATE TABLE TagList (
    TagId          nvarchar(40)     NOT NULL,
    ReferenceGuid  uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    ReferenceId    int              NOT NULL,
    ObjectType     nvarchar(40)     NOT NULL
)
```

For example, to tag an object with a uniqueidentifier primary key with the word 'example', the TagList record would look like this:

```
TagList (
    TagId          'example',
    ReferenceGuid  '1e93d578-321b-4f86-8b0f-32435d385bd7',
    ReferenceId    0,
    ObjectType     'Customer'
)
```

To tag an object with an integer primary key with the word 'example', the TagList record would look like this:

```
TagList (
    TagId          'example',
    ReferenceGuid  '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
    ReferenceId    5639,
    ObjectType     'Product'
)
```

In practice, either the TagId and the ReferenceGuid column must be unique or, if an int primary key object is being defined, the TagId, ReferenceId and ObjectType must be unique.

To simplify(?) things, making the combination of all four columns to be unique would also serve the same functional purpose.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: How is ObjectType related with reference guid and reference id? Let me know if there exists any functional dependency of Object Type on these two columns?

Comment: In terms of definition, the Object Type is not strictly necessary when defining an object with a unique identifier primary key. When defining an object with an integer primary key, the Object Type distinguishes one id from another, e.g. Id 27, say, could refer to a Product or a Customer, the Object Type defines which. The Object Type is also used for Tag searches: find all the Customers with a tag of 'example'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a multi column primary key should do the trick

```
CREATE TABLE TagList (
    TagId          nvarchar(40)     NOT NULL,
    ReferenceGuid  uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    ReferenceId    int              NOT NULL,
    ObjectType     nvarchar(40)     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_TagList PRIMARY KEY (TagId,ReferenceGuid,ReferenceId,ObjectType)
)
```

Comment: Hi Lee, this was my original plan, but when I investigated this, I found several posts suggesting that this approach would not be ideal for performance reasons and it would be better to introduce a surrogate primary key (e.g. identity integer) and than add specific indexes to control the 'uniqueness' of either TagId+ReferenceGuid or TagId+ReferenceId+ObjectType.  Certainly your suggestion seems simpler.

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't read your question fully, having a constraint this way would enforce uniqueness on entry where as having an additional entry to manage the identity would rely on ReferenceGuid and ReferenceId being entered as unique each time.
I think looking at your structure you wouldn't need all four in your constraint only ReferenceGuid & ReferenceId? 
I personally would also pull ObjectType out into a separate table linking to TagList on a ObjectTypeId foreign key.

Comment: If ReferenceId is incremental I would advice to put it at beginning of primary key. If you don't design CLUSTERED index manually it will be the same as PRIMARY KEY. If ReferenceId is incremental then every new row will be stored at the end of table (at the end of page, in fact). If TagId will be first and this is alphanumeric unordered entity, then every new row will be stored "randomly" in the middle of table (in the middle of page, in fact) - so fragmentation of pages may appear.

Comment: Multi-column keys may have some disadventages like longer foreign keys or making some solutions unable to apply (for example FULL TEXT SEARCH requires to have one column primary key). On other side multi-column keys may be more readable (example: parent id + child local id + sub child local id).

Comment: Thanks Lee, this feels like a much cleaner approach

Answer (score 1):

If you only require a unique constraint, and not a primary key, this can be used:

```
ALTER TABLE TagList
ADD CONSTRAINT UK_TagList_1 UNIQUE
(
    TagId,
    ReferenceGuid,
    ReferenceId,
    ObjectType
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not have all the information of the entities involved,  but with the limited visibility I have I would try to suggest following first cut design :

Create two separate tables, one with TagId and ReferenceGuid and the other with TagId and ReferenceId. I am not sure of ObjectType though. If ObjectType is not implicit then this too can be maintained in both of these tables. Then a view can be created on top of these tables to shoot queries on which can contain all the required columns.
This way we can get around the issue of space wastage in current design.
Please give your input if this design doesn't solve the problem in hand.

Comment: Thank you Dipendu, this was similar to the final approach suggested above and looks like a much cleaner/better structured approach.